# Can we have 50 users per page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, users-page

I've never understood why we have 5 columns of 7 rows per user page. 35 is an unusual number for this kind of thing. There certainly is no lack of room. Users is one of the shorter pages.

Why not increase is to 5 columns of 10 or 50 per page? Nice round number.

Comment: 64 would be a nice round number.

Comment: 4 columns of 16?

Comment: +1 'coz that would probably get me back onto the first page of users. :)

Comment: I would like 6 columns of 7 rows... If 42 top SO users cannot find the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything... I don't know who can ;)

Answer (score 3):

Also the ordering of the users is something that always confused me when i saw it first.

Answer (score 2):

We were trying to get designs that *mostly* fit on 1024x768 displays -- or at least the key pagination was visible at that resolution, anyway.

Comment: 1024x768 - That's what I call conservative.

Comment: Do you have any data on the resolutions of SO users? I'd imagine most programmers are operating on something higher :)

Comment: 1024 width is about the largest you should design for so that's correct but the users page is one of the shortest on the site. I think it could take 3 more rows NP.

Comment: Not everyone keeps their browser at the widest possible screen width, nor like having to scan a long distance from side to side.